# Azure CDN - Images Respond 404 to CURL

Tags: azure

We have a vendor who sends us photos that are hosted on Azure Edge. These photos are available and I can download them, but if we do a CURL request we get a 404 roughly 4 out of 5 times. If we do a HEAD request to get the filesize, we get a 404 about 7 out of 10 times. On our production server, we get a 404 100% of the time. Any idea how we might work around this or if there's another way to check these files without the vendor having to fix their issue?

**Sample file:**
curl -I http://tdrvehicles2.azureedge.net/photos/202008/1419/1850/f253435f-86b1-4cc4-b95c-7756addddad4.jpg

````
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Thu, 19 Aug 2021 14:12:54 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2020 14:12:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive```
````

Comment: After creating a CDN endpoint, it will not immediately be available for use, as it takes time for the registration to propagate through the CDN

Comment: I don't believe that's what this is. Otherwise the result would be consistent? This happens to thousands of images that have been in the CDN for weeks.